# Microsoft Word 365 Content Controls Tab Order in Text Box

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-word-2016

I am trying to create a template with content control fields and some text boxes in fixed positions using the newest Microsoft Word 365.

The content controls themselves work fine but when using the template I cannot tab between the fields in and outside of the text boxes. When inside a textbox tab just cycles through all the fields inside the box.

Is there any way to change this behaviour? The template is meant to be used for windowed envelopes so I need a way to accurately position the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It might work if you use a Group Content Control for your entire document, but I thing the best method would be to...*

### Use Frames rather than Text Boxes

This is the standard way Word positions addresses on an envelope, but you can use it in the letter itself. Here is my page on [Textboxes and Frames in Word](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage).

Here is a link to that part of the page on how to [Creating Frames in Word](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#CreatingFrames).

In brief, there are two methods:

1. Use the Frame button under Legacy Controls on the [Developer Tab](http://addbalance.com/word/developertab.htm), or
2. Create/Modify a Style to include a Frame definition.

*All links are to pages on my website.*

Comment: Thanks. 1. Is there any way to align text vertically in a frame? I need to align the text in one of the frames to the bottom. 2. How do I group the content controls in the text boxes? There is no way to select the controls in the text boxes together with the controls in the main document.

Comment: There is no way to vertically "align" text in a frame. You can use space-before paragraph formatting, though. Text boxes are in a different layer than the body of the document. -- You can select all and apply the Group Content Control, which is different from the grouping used with shapes.

Comment: Okay, that's unfortunate. So even though I group everything together tabbing does not work because there are different layers?

Comment: Did you try it using the Group Content Control? Frames are in the same layer as body text as are Tables. Text Boxes are not; however tabbing should still work. The order of Text Boxes (and their content) is determined by the location of the "anchor" for the text box.

Comment: Word did not let me select both content controls inside and outside of the text boxes in order to group them. I ended up using a mix of tables and frames and found it quite useful to be able to add frame definitions to my custom styles. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Tables are often a good substitute for Text Boxes.